# Trouble with imagepng

Tags: php, header, png, gd

I am struggling with PHP's GD library.

I have written a script called foo.php which outputs a png:

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
$img = imagecreatefrompng($url) or die('bad url:'.$url);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

It works fine.  Its purpose is to accept a GET parameter and then spit out the appropriate graph:

(e.g.)  `foo.php?id=2` puts a nice graph in any browser.

**Here's my problem:**

In another script (baz.php), I'd like to use `readfile` or something similar to take the image created by foo.php and have baz.php send it to the browser.  ***But no matter what I try, it won't seem to work when I call baz.php***

Example from baz.php:

```
switch($id) {
    case '1':
         readfile('foo.php?id=1');
         break;
    case '2':
         readfile('foo.php?id=2');
         break;
    // and so on...
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory...
```

If I put in the full url or the path:

```
readfile('http://localhost/dev/foo.php?id=1');
readfile('C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/foo.php?id=1');
```

...I get the same error.

If I add the header to baz.php:

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
readfile($url);
```

In firefox I get "The image "http://localhost/dev/baz.php" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.  In Chrome it shows a broken image 27.82kb in size with dimensions of 0x0

*allow_url_fopen* is on, and as I mentioned, foo.php is producing pngs without any problems; I just can't seem to get in out of baz.php, which I need to.

I can, for instance just put:

```
header("Location: foo.php?id=1");
```

and it will redirect and output the image, but I don't want to do a 302 redirect, **I need baz.php to push the image out to the browser.**  If I save the file as a static file, it will load that fine as well.  *It just doesn't seem to want to handle the dynamic file.*

Any help is very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work `readfile('http://localhost/dev/foo.php?id=1');` is `localhost` the correct host name from the server's point of view?

Comment: @Pekka - I know it *should*.  But it doesn't.  To reiterate, if I do readfile('http://localhost/dev/foo.php?id=1') I get a failed to open error.  If I paste http://localhost/dev/foo.php?id=1 into the browser it opens fine.  If I then save the image as temp_foo.png and do readfile('temp_foo.png') *that* also opens fine.  localhost is the correct host.  (FYI SO is removing the 'http' but it's there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Figured it out:

**Issue #1:**

You cannot use php's `readfile()` to include a png that is generated dynamically by php *if it is on the same server*.

Why? **Because readfile will include the raw php code rather than rendering that php code into an image**.  If you want to call it from another server, readfile works fine.

So, you can include/require the file instead (so it will be rendered into a png), however...

**Issue #2:**

You cannot include a file with parameters / query string directly (e.g. the following code will error that it cannot open the file:

```
include('baz.php?id=1'); //this won't work
```

### Solution:

- Set the parameter manually in the GET string (e.g. `$_GET['id'] = 1;`)
- Include the file: `include('baz.php');`

*Also note: Apache's `virtual()` command will also not work with GET because only QUERY_STRING is passed along ($_GET is copied from the parent script):*

[PHP.net's description of virtual()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php)

Comment: It's great of you to post the solution (I wish everybody did that!), but your conclusions are incorrect, sorry :) `readfile will include the raw php code rather than rendering that php code into an image` it will *definitely* work from *any* location, including the same server, if you specify  a `http://` path. If it does, something is seriously wrong with your configuration! Just note that `localhost` always points to the same machine (it's a synonym for 127.0.0.1 and *not* a valid host name).

Comment: @Pekka: It should, but **did you try it?** Even with a wrapper it does not work on the same server for me: (Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9) Here's some test code:
<?PHP //foo.php
$url  = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World';
$url = 'http://localhost/dev/baz.php';
readfile($url);
?><?PHP //baz.php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($url);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>

Comment: Ack - SO nerf'd my code in the comment again.  Bottom line is, I tried it with a wrapper and it does not work on the same server.  There are scattered mentions of it I found googling (e.g. http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?4620-Calling-PHP-function-readfile()-on-own-domain-fails)

Comment: really, really strange - have never encountered this before. I can't try this out right now - if I get around to it in the next couple of days, I'll give feedback.

Answer (score -1):

this should work http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: it's a little nicer debugging, but it's still the same problem - it won't open the file if it's dynamic (LoadPNG will give "error loading" and the filename 'localhost/dev/foo.php?id=1', which, if I paste it into the browser (with or without the http) loads fine.